# Fields & Field Groups in Dashboard

Tags: joomla-4.x, com-fields, dashboard

In my component I have the fields and field groups showing in my dashboard (admin side) and working no problems at all but I wanted to have a config param to switch it on/off like the content component.
I have done this for the Workflow using exactly the same config element as com_content but the fields aspect doesn't get hidden when param set to no.
Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <field
            name="workflow_enabled"
            type="radio"
            label="JWORKFLOW_ENABLED_LABEL"
            class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
            default="0" >
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
        </field>
```

The above works nicely for the Workflow.

```
        <field
            name="custom_fields_enable"
            type="radio"
            label="JGLOBAL_CUSTOM_FIELDS_ENABLE_LABEL"
            class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
            default="0" >
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
        </field>
```

This one doesn't work and I can't find where the code is that switches this on/off?

More Info:

This is the code I have in my Dashboard preset:

```
    <menuitem
        title="COM_CONTENT_MENUS_WORKFLOW"
        type="component"
        element="com_workflow"
        link="index.php?option=com_workflow&amp;view=workflows&amp;extension=com_mycomponent"
    />

    <menuitem
        title="MOD_MENU_FIELDS"
        type="component"
        element="com_fields"
        link="index.php?option=com_fields&amp;view=fields&amp;context=com_mycomponent"
    />

    <menuitem
        title="MOD_MENU_FIELDS_GROUP"
        type="component"
        element="com_fields"
        link="index.php?option=com_fields&amp;view=groups&amp;context=com_mycomponent"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure which piece of this is going to apply to what you are asking but I found the following that might give you some ideas about how Workflow hides itself.

**administrator/components/com_content/tmpl/articles/default.php** line #59

```
if ($workflow_enabled) :
    $wa->getRegistry()->addExtensionRegistryFile('com_workflow');
    $wa->useScript('com_workflow.admin-items-workflow-buttons')
    ->useScript('com_content.articles-status');

    $workflow_state    = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_content')->isFunctionalityUsed('core.state', 'com_content.article');
    $workflow_featured = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_content')->isFunctionalityUsed('core.featured', 'com_content.article');
endif;
```

**administrator/components/com_content/src/Model/ArticlesModel.php** line #96

```
public function getFilterForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    $form = parent::getFilterForm($data, $loadData);

    $params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');

    if (!$params->get('workflow_enabled')) {
        $form->removeField('stage', 'filter');
    } else {
        $ordering = $form->getField('fullordering', 'list');

        $ordering->addOption('JSTAGE_ASC', ['value' => 'ws.title ASC']);
        $ordering->addOption('JSTAGE_DESC', ['value' => 'ws.title DESC']);
    }

    return $form;
```

**administrator/components/com_content/src/View/Featured/HtmlView.php** line #107

```
if (ComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('workflow_enabled')) {
    PluginHelper::importPlugin('workflow');

    $this->transitions = $this->get('Transitions');
}
```

Update: 11th September

Glen, the only two places I can find the `custom_fields_enable` value is checked to see if it is set is in the Menu and  Sub Menu processing that toggles whether it is hidden(removed) or not from the left sidebar menu of the Admin pages.

**administrator/modules/mod_submenu/src/Menu/Menu.php** at line #139

```
        // Only display Fields menus when enabled in the component
        $createFields = null;

        if (isset($query['context'])) {
            $createFields = ComponentHelper::getParams(strstr($query['context'], '.', true))->get('custom_fields_enable', 1);
        }

        if (!$createFields || !$user->authorise('core.manage', 'com_users')) {
            $parent->removeChild($item);
            continue;
        }
```

**administrator/modules/mod_menu/src/Menu/CssMenu.php** at line #339

```
        // Only display Fields menus when enabled in the component
        $createFields = null;

        if (isset($query['context'])) {
            $createFields = ComponentHelper::getParams(strstr($query['context'], '.', true))->get('custom_fields_enable', 1);
        }

        if (!$createFields) {
            $parent->removeChild($item);
            continue;
        }

        list($assetName) = isset($query['context']) ? explode('.', $query['context'], 2) : array('com_fields');
```

Similar code for WorkFlow exists in same Classes however the Custom field checks `$query['context']` the Workflow checks for `$query['extension']`, maybe that gives you some clue to why they are working differently.

**administrator/modules/mod_menu/src/Menu/CssMenu.php** at line #366

```
        // Only display Workflow menus when enabled in the component
        $workflow = null;

        if (isset($query['extension'])) {
            $parts = explode('.', $query['extension']);

            $workflow = ComponentHelper::getParams($parts[0])->get('workflow_enabled') && $user->authorise('core.manage.workflow', $parts[0]);
        }

        if (!$workflow) {
            $parent->removeChild($item);
            continue;
        }

        list($assetName) = isset($query['extension']) ? explode('.', $query['extension'], 2) : array('com_workflow');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is beneficial to have this knowledge for future use, however, I have none of this code in my current component and Workflow hides/shows in the dashboard just by having the options set in config.xml of  <field name="workflow_enabled" type="radio" default="0" . . . So I'm still at a loss because I have the option -> <field name="custom_fields_enable" type="radio" default="0" . . . as is the case in com_content but it doesn't hide?

Comment: I have updated some more places where I found code that hides the menu items for Workflow and Custom Fields.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for spending the time to help with this, I'll see how I can use the context aspect to get this working and update this post accordingly.  Thank you so much.